# How can I display all the array value in another php page

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to display the value of an array in which is passed from one php page to another php page, but I am getting only last element value. Where as when I checked the array content using print_r() it is showing all the values.
This is where I need to the value to be displayed -

```
<tr class="bgcolor_02">
  <?php
    if(is_array($subject_array))
    {
    foreach($subject_array as $each_subject)
    {
  ?>
  <td width="9%"> <?php echo ucfirst($each_subject['es_subjectname']);?> </td>
  <?php } } ?>
</tr>
<tr>
  <?php
  $inc=0;
  foreach($subject_array as $each_subject)
  {
  ?>
  <td> <?php echo $array_roll[$inc]; ?> </td>
  <?php $inc++;
  }?>
</tr>
```

And here is the code from where values are fetched and passed -

```
if(count($errormessage)==0)
{
  $cout=0;
  if(isset($classid))
  {
    $subject_array=$db->getRows("SELECT * FROM es_subject WHERE es_subjectshortname='".$classid."'");
    if(is_array($subject_array))
    {
       foreach($subject_array as $each_subject)
       {
      $array_subject[$each_subject['es_subjectid']]=$each_subject['es_subjectname'];

      $sub_id=$each_subject['es_subjectid'];
      $roll_array=$db->getRow("SELECT es_exam_detailsid FROM es_exam_details WHERE academicexam_id='".$exam_id."' AND subject_id='".$sub_id."'");               
          $array_roll[$cout]=$roll_array['es_exam_detailsid'];
      print_r($array_roll[$cout]."  ");
    }
      }
   }
}
```

By this code I am getting Output like this
ENGLISH GEOGRAPHY ACCOUNTANCY COMPUTER ECONOMICS
33
Where as output must be 
ENGLISH GEOGRAPHY ACCOUNTANCY COMPUTER ECONOMICS
26            27                   31                       32                 33

I am able to see the values on top of the page due to print_r(); which is like this 
26 27 31 32 33

Need some help on this problem why I am not getting all values

Comment: Protip: you can use the `{}` button in the Post Editor to post the output text as well. Saves you some time messing with `&nbsp;`s :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($subject_array as $each_subject)
       {
      $array_subject[$each_subject['es_subjectid']]=$each_subject['es_subjectname'];

      $sub_id=$each_subject['es_subjectid'];
      $roll_array=$db->getRow("SELECT es_exam_detailsid FROM es_exam_details WHERE     academicexam_id='".$exam_id."' AND subject_id='".$sub_id."'");               
          $array_roll[$cout]=$roll_array['es_exam_detailsid'];
      $cout++; //HERE YOU MUST HAVE++
    }
```

AND will be good.

Comment: I have done this, it works on local testing, but after uploading giving warning and no numbers Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/cbsecop2/public_html/manazeschool.com/software/office_admin/templates/impo‌​rt_marks.tpl.php on line 121 this error is in 2nd foreach($subject_array as $each_subject)

Comment: It worked perfectly on localhost I tested and then I accepted, as you also suggested same thing and really it worked. But after uploading it on server showing error

Comment: Where in 1st part of the code or in 2nd part of the code shown above

Comment: try $subject_array = array(); it will help

Comment: @serigo No effect I tried this `<?php
   `for($i=0;i<$inc;$i++)
    `{
    `?>
    `<td> <?php echo $array_roll[$i]; ?> </td>
    `<?php 
    `}?>    Output came without warning BUT Browser hangs and throw me out on login page

Comment: GOT the mistake `i<$inc  $missing now its perfect working online also. Thank you for tour extended cooperatin.

Answer (score 1):

Had to tell exactly what is going on because of poor code formatting and non-meaningful variable names, but I am guessing your problem might lie here:

```
$array_roll[$cout]=$roll_array['es_exam_detailsid'];
```

You never change the value for `$cout`, so you are just continually overwriting the value and array index position 0.

Comment: BrantThank you very much showing me my silly mistake. It works I can't vote you up because of less reputation. But surely I will accept your reply. Thank you again

Comment: ON localhost while testing its work but now I am getting warning `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/cbsecop2/public_html/manazeschool.com/software/office_admin/templates/import_marks.tpl.php on line 121 ------ SAME CODE NO CHANGE onlu cout++ added

Comment: @user3100533 it probably means you don't have an iterable object/array that you are trying to work with in foreach.

Comment: Give me some clue how to come out of this ?

Comment: @user3100533 I have no idea what line of code that is or what value you get for the item trying to be iterated (you need to var_dump or similar to determine that).  This is just basic debugging that you should gain familiarity with how to do.